# Magento 2: Override Price of shipping if customer is logged in?

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, rules

How would I **override** the **price of shipping** if a customer is logged in?

> For example, Flat rate shipping for guest checkout is $4.99 but if you are logged in you can get it for $2.99.

I do no understand right now how the KnockoutJS is pulling the price in for the shipping method.

Answer (score 2):

> Create plugin

```
<type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate">
        <plugin name="flaterate_custom_shipping"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Flatrate" />
</type>
```

> Plugin file

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class Flatrate
{
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $rateResultFactory;
    protected $rateMethodFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
    }   

    public function afterCollectRates(\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate $subject, $result)
    {
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
        $shippingPrice = "4.99"; //custom price

        if (!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
            $method->setCarrier('flatrate');
            $method->setCarrierTitle($subject->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod('flatrate');
            $method->setMethodTitle($subject->getConfigData('name'));

            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);
            
            $result->append($method);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add rules to apply the discount to loggedin users using the **cart rules** like that image below.

[image: magento2 shippment amount discount]

Comment: I would like that same functionality, but for the shipping prices not product prices. Do you know if that is available via admin or programmatically?

Comment: I changed my answer @TylerLHM